# Is it possible to add a CI/CD pipeline to an existing app service on Azure? If so, how?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

I have an existing app service running on Azure that I previously published directly from Visual Studio. I am trying to get to grips with using DevOps and was wondering if it is possible to add a CI/CD pipeline to an existing app service.

I have seen a lot of tutorials on the web about how to create a pipeline for a new app service (many, of course, are out of date and do not actually relate to what one sees in the Azure portal!) So far, though, I have not come across anything about adding this to an existing app service.

Any advice or links to handy tutorials would be greatly appreciated!

I am hoping that the answer is not delete the existing service and start again from scratch!

Answer (score 1):

If you are a beginner on Azure Devops, I will recommend to use the [Azure Devops Starter project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops-project/overview) to create a pipeline, you can pick AppService as the deployment.

Once the pipelines are created on the Azure Devops , just open the pipeline and select the existing AppService where you want to deploy and also the source from where you want to pull the code. This makes easier rather than creating the stuffs from the scratch.